# MRS not invariant under monotonic transformation

Tags: consumer-theory

*Consider U(x, y) = ln(x)ln(y). Is it quasi-linear?*

My response was no, since applying an exponential would yield exp(ln(x)ln(y))= exp(ln(x+y)) = x+y.

However, the original MRS was (y/x)(ln(y)/ln(x)). Now it's 1. What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that $\exp(\ln(x)\ln(y))= \exp(\ln(x+y))$?

Comment: @HerrK. That's an answer (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\exp(\ln(x)\ln(y))\ne \exp(\ln(x+y))$. Instead,
\begin{equation}
\exp(\ln(x)\ln(y))=x^{\ln y}=y^{\ln x}. 
\end{equation}
The MRS of the monotonically transformed utility is still $\frac{y\ln y}{x\ln x}$.